# Cannot select items in bootstrap dropdown due to overlap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I can’t select elements of the bootstrap drop-down list due to overlapping by another element, as in the screenshot the footer overlaps the two lower elements of the list and they cannot be selected.

I use bootstrap styles.

Such a problem with all dropdowns ...

How to solve this problem?

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <div id="select-form-control">
                        <label for="teamUsers">Выберите участников</label>
                        <div class="dropdown bootstrap-select show-tick form-control show" style="width: 97%;">
                            <select id="teamUsers" name="teamUsers" class="selectpicker form-control"
                                    data-actions-box="true" data-dropup-auto="false" data-live-search="true"
                                    data-selected-text-format="count" data-size="10"
                                    data-style="btn-info text-white" data-width="97%" multiple="" required=""
                                    tabindex="-98">
                                <option value="5">stud stud</option>
                                <option value="3">student student</option>
                                <option value="3">student student</option>
                                <option value="4">student student</option>
                            </select>
                            <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-info text-white bs-placeholder"
                                    data-toggle="dropdown" role="combobox" aria-owns="bs-select-1"
                                    aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-expanded="true" data-id="teamUsers"
                                    title="Ничего не выбрано">
                                <div class="filter-option">
                                    <div class="filter-option-inner">
                                        <div class="filter-option-inner-inner">Ничего не выбрано</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </button>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu show" x-placement="bottom-start"
                                 style="overflow: hidden; position: absolute; will-change: transform; top: 0px; left: 0px; transform: translate3d(6px, 52px, 0px);">
                                <div class="bs-searchbox"><input type="search" class="form-control"
                                                                 autocomplete="off" role="combobox"
                                                                 aria-label="Search" aria-controls="bs-select-1"
                                                                 aria-autocomplete="list"></div>
                                <div class="bs-actionsbox">
                                    <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm btn-block">
                                        <button type="button" class="actions-btn bs-select-all btn btn-light">
                                            Выбрать все
                                        </button>
                                        <button type="button" class="actions-btn bs-deselect-all btn btn-light">
                                            Отменить все
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="inner show" role="listbox" id="bs-select-1" tabindex="-1"
                                     aria-multiselectable="true" style="overflow-y: auto;">
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu inner show" role="presentation"
                                        style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
                                        <li><a role="option" class="dropdown-item" id="bs-select-1-0" tabindex="0"
                                               aria-selected="false" aria-setsize="4" aria-posinset="1"><span
                                                        class=" bs-ok-default check-mark"></span><span class="text">stud stud</span></a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a role="option" class="dropdown-item" id="bs-select-1-1" tabindex="0"
                                               aria-selected="false" aria-setsize="4" aria-posinset="2"><span
                                                        class=" bs-ok-default check-mark"></span><span class="text">student student</span></a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a role="option" class="dropdown-item" id="bs-select-1-2" tabindex="0"
                                               aria-selected="false"><span class=" bs-ok-default check-mark"></span><span
                                                        class="text">student student</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a role="option" class="dropdown-item" id="bs-select-1-3" tabindex="0"
                                               aria-selected="false"><span class=" bs-ok-default check-mark"></span><span
                                                        class="text">student student</span></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

[image]

Comment: have you try giving higher z-index for option?

Comment: no, with the modified z-index also overlaps

Comment: If u have dev instance, then share the URL since css nothing can tell without inspect..